# How to get the value closest to another value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming that I have the following dataframe:

```
           col1       col2
0          blue      0.400
1          test      0.255
2        yellow      0.460
```

How can I get the single value from `col2` which is closest to the corresponding value where `col1='test'`? To make things more clear, I want to find the value closest to `0.255` (which in this case is `0.400`) and then the corresponding value in `col1` that has the closest value, i.e. in this case it would be `blue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `idxmin`

```
def s(d, t): return d.sub(d.pop(t)).abs().idxmin()
df.set_index('col1').col2.pipe(s, t='test')

'blue'
```

Same thing but with `min` and `dict`

```
d = dict(zip(df.col1, df.col2))

v = d.pop('test')
min(d, key=lambda x: abs(d[x] - v))

'blue'
```

Comment: nice, i was just about to post the same solution using numpy and `argmin()` but this is much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It works fine - I have updated my question though as I mis-described the desired output. So after finding the closest value, I am interested in the value of `col1` that has the closest `col2` value. In this case, the desired output will be `blue`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
m = df['col1'].eq('test')
df.loc[df['col2'].sub(df['col2'].where(m)
                                .bfill()
                                .ffill())
                 .abs()
                 .mask(m).idxmin(),'col2']
```

or

```
m = df['col1'].eq('test')
df.loc[df['col2'].sub(df.loc[m,'col2'].iloc[0])
                 .abs()
                 .mask(m).idxmin(),'col2']
```

**Output**

```
0.4
```

---

**References**

- [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)
- [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html)
- [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)
- [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)
- [`Series.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html)
- [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)
- [`Series.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html)
- [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: I think your answer is not accurate, in case the closest value equals to the value in 'test' (and the diff is 0)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[(df['col2']-df[df['col1']=='test']['col2'].values).abs().sort_values().index[1]]['col2']
```

output:

```
Out[38]: 0.4
```